# Active Directory Password Authentication for Azure SQL not working

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, azure-sql-server, azure-security, azure-authentication

I followed all the [mentioned](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-aad-authentication) steps but couldn't get it to work with "Active Directory Password Authentication" for AD principal which is a contained user in my SampleDB. I get this error:

> Cannot connect to sql01.database.windows.net.
>
> ADDITIONAL INFORMATION:
>
> Failed to authenticate the user user@customDomain.com in Active
>   Directory (Authentication=ActiveDirectoryPassword).
>
> Error code 0xCAA20003; state 10
>
> ID3242: The security token could not be authenticated or authorized.
>   (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 0)

We are using Ping Federate as our federation provider.

To my surprise, "Active Directory Integrated Authentication" works for the same user. Do we need to open some firewalls or ports at our on-prem environment to make it work?

Comment: Please create a support case. ADAL.DLL had issues in the past with Ping Federate so the support team would be the best to look into it

Answer (score 1):

Please create a support case. ADAL.DLL had issues in the past with Ping Federate so the support team would be the best to look into it

Comment: hi..I am seeing the same error and we are using ping identity too. where can I track work that is being done to fix this issue.